# Android reopen the application when it closes

Tags: android

I am making an application to an Android TV dongle and it must run about 10 hours per day.

But it always closes after about 4 hours running, but no error appears on adb and there os no memory leak... it consumes about 14Mb memory when it closes.

Is there an way to avoid it closes or reopen the application when it get closed?

By the way... I think that the closing behaviour is an dongle issue, because even native application like settings get suddenly closed after some time...

Comment: Is the app in the foreground at the time? If not, Android routinely terminates background processes as part of the normal lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, it is on foreground and it closes suddenly

Comment: If you're not seeing any stack traces or other signs of a crash, that definitely feels like it is an issue with the hardware. You could try adding a superfluous foreground service to see if that helps. Otherwise, you're probably at some sort of `AlarmManager`-based "heartbeat" to try to restart you if your process is no longer running.